# BasicHTTPBinding from app.config to code

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm stuck with implementing a BasicHTTPBinding formerly defined in the app.config (which does not exist in a class library). I want this settings to be predefined and thus hard coded in my .dll.

Here's what my app.config says:

```
<!-- language: xaml -->
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ImageServerServiceSoapBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx/xyz" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ImageServerServiceSoapBinding" contract="xyz.ImageServer" name="ImageServerPort"/>
</client>
```

I started to set up the binding programmatically but stuck pretty fast by not having the methods in my _binding that were set in the app.config?!

```
<!-- language: c# -->
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding _binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress _address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(@"http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxx/xyz");

_binding.Name = "ImageServerServiceSoapBinding";
_binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
_binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
_binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
_binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);

this._Client = new ImageServerClient(_binding, _address);

_Settings.TraverseData.TraverseWidth = double.Parse(_Client.getCameraInfo(d2els_selectedcam).traverseLength);
```

The last line fails due to an uncompatible content type (multipart/related;) from the binding to the client (text/xml; charset=utf-8)?!

How can I access those settings in the BasicHTTPBinding? Or do I have a wrong concept?

```
_binding.maxDepth // ... etc.
```

are no members of the BasicHTTPBinding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for all of you who will face the same problem:

It took google and quite a long time to find the base classes in the framework that are simply named in the app.config. The app.config above will look like as follows in code:

```
        System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding _binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
        System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress _address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(@"http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxx/xyz");

        _binding.Name = "ImageServerServiceSoapBinding";
        _binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
        _binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
        _binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
        _binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);

        _binding.MessageEncoding = System.ServiceModel.WSMessageEncoding.Mtom;
        _binding.AllowCookies = false;
        _binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
        _binding.HostNameComparisonMode = System.ServiceModel.HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
        _binding.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
        _binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = Int16.MaxValue;
        _binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
        _binding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        _binding.TransferMode = System.ServiceModel.TransferMode.Buffered;
        _binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;

        System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas _readerquotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();

        _readerquotas.MaxDepth = Int32.MaxValue;
        _readerquotas.MaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        _readerquotas.MaxArrayLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        _readerquotas.MaxBytesPerRead = Int32.MaxValue;
        _readerquotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = Int32.MaxValue;

        _binding.ReaderQuotas = _readerquotas;

        _binding.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
        _binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.None;
        _binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
        _binding.Security.Transport.Realm = "";

        _binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
        _binding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default;

        this._Client = new ImageServerClient(_binding, _address);
```

My problem was that I thought the ImageServerClient function expects a

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding
```

but also accepted a

```
System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding.
```

The latter contains all the expected methods; connecting to the server works now without the app.config file :)